# What is the best way to get a Vue app to correctly read the env variables that have been set on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, heroku

I have a vue app that is being hosted on Heroku. Now, because heroku doesn't do static apps, I wrote a simple express server to serve this app

```
//server.js

const express = require('express')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
const path = require('path')

app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https'
      ? res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname + req.originalUrl)
      : next()
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

const port = process.env.PORT || 80

app.listen(port)
```

And hooked the build process of the app to Heroku existing workflow through `package.json`

```
.
.
.
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "postinstall": "if test \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"production\" ; then yarn run build ; fi",
    "start": "node server.js"
},
.
.
.
```

This whole thing works and technically so do the environment variables. However, I see that some env variables that I set on heroku (in their dashboards) yesterday are still undefined when I access them in vue using `process.env.VUE_APP_XXX`.

In development I use `.env` and that works as intended. My idea here is that because there's the express server in the middle things don't work as I would have expected.

Is there any way to make this thing work smoothly or am I better off using a static site hosting a-la Netflify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ENV variables in Vue CLI (or Webpack build app in general) is done using Webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) which replaces the values like `process.env.VUE_APP_XXX` in your code at **build time**

So if you define (or change) your variables directly in Heroku dashboard instead of `.env` file committed to repo, you need to rebuild you app **on Heroku** to pick up the changes...

If you are using ENV to configure any secrets (API keys etc), don't !! These values will be included directly in JS bundle of your app and easily accessible to anyone...

Comment: Thanks Michal! That helped, somehow I thought that when I added an env variable to heroku, heroku would rebuild the app but looking at the logs it simply reboots the dyno and starts the app.

Do you know if there's any way I could tell heroku to do a full rebuild when an environment variable is added?

Comment: Sorry I do not know if it is possible to do that automatically

Comment: I had to change my env variable and rebuild the app. Thanks @MichalLevý

Answer (score 0):

You can use heroku cli to set your env variables - [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URI=database_uri_here
$ heroku config:set SESSION_SECRET=session_secret
... and so on for each variable,
```

OR

if you have the env variables set in your .env file then you can do this as well

```
heroku config:set $(cat .env | sed '/^$/d; /#[[:print:]]*$/d')
```